# Downloaded language-check for python. Try to import and get no attribute error

Tags: python, import

I downloaded the python lib language-check.
I try to import language_check and get the following issue

```
>>> import language_check
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\language_che
ck\__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW'
```

I tried to import subprocess, then import this library, but no luck. I'm sure I'm looking over something trivial. Some insight would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you recently installed Python 3.x. 
This is a "version like" problem.

You can make a reinstall or the following will help you, I guess:

```
import subprocess
import _subprocess

startupinfo.dwFlags |= _subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
```

Comment: I did python --version and got Python 2.7.1